# Simply function to separte buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have very basic problem, actually it's look [Here](http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/9/). I want to separate two buttons.

**jQuery**

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span>↓ Hobby </span>
<p class="contentDiv" >Such interesting text, eh?</p>
    <br> <br>
 <span>↓ Sport </span>
<p class="contentDiv" >Such interesting text, eh?</p>
```

I was trying by getElementById but it doesn't work.

I'm beginner, be patient.

Comment: What do you mean by separate?

Comment: Anton solve my problem :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `$('p')` you are selecting all p elements, you need to specify like this

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest('p').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Closest gets the closest parent, that won't work since <p> is a sibling